# Add property to an IEnumerable from property comparison between IEnumerable's

Tags: linq, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a webapi that reads data from two different schemas in MySQL, `customers` and `simuladoMurex`. From reading the customers schema, the webapi makes a json available on the server like the one below:

```
[
    {
        "customer": "Itau",
        "email": "itau@hotmail.com"
    },
    {
        "customer": "Jordan Banks",
        "email": "jordan@hotmail.com"
    },
    {
        "customer": "Santander",
        "email": "santander@hotmail.com"
    }
]
```

I have the `customers` class where I read the data above:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SimuladoMurex.Domain.Entities.Customers
{
    public class Customers
    {
        public string Customer { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Customers> LoadData(IEnumerable<Customers> data)
        {
            return data.Select(x => new Customers
            {
                Customer = x.Customer,
                Email = x.Email
            }).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

And from reading the `simuladoMurex`, I have the following json:

```
[
    {
        "counterparty": "Santander",
        "rc": [
            {
                "tradeDate": "2020-05-23T10:03:12",
                "isin": "DOL110",
                "typology": 0
            },
            {
                "tradeDate": "2020-06-11T11:24:08",
                "isin": "LIT300",
                "typology": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "counterparty": "Jordan Banks",
        "rc": [
            {
                "tradeDate": "2020-06-11T11:23:22",
                "isin": "LIT250",
                "typology": 0
            },
            {
                "tradeDate": "2020-06-11T18:08:44",
                "isin": "CIT450",
                "typology": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "counterparty": "Itau",
        "rc": [
            {
                "tradeDate": "2020-06-11T18:06:53",
                "isin": "LIT350",
                "typology": 0
            },
            {
                "tradeDate": "2020-06-11T18:07:10",
                "isin": "LIT450",
                "typology": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In the domain, I have the following classes to map data for the service:

```
using System;

namespace SimuladoMurex.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Mo
    {
        public int MoId { get; set; }
        public DateTime TradeDate { get; set; }
        public string Counterparty { get; set; }     

        public Ir Ir { get; set; }
    }

    public class Ir
    {
        public int MoId { get; set; }
        public string Isin { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Trader { get; set; }

        public virtual Mo Mo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the classes below, where I do the grouping and loading of the data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SimuladoMurex.Domain.Entities.Reports
{
    public class ReportCustomers
    {
        public DateTime TradeDate { get; set; }
        public string Isin { get; set; }
        public int Typology { get; set; 
        }
        
    }

    public class ReportCustomerKey
    {
        public string Counterparty { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ReportCustomers> rc { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ReportCustomerKey> LoadData(IEnumerable<Mo> data)
        {
            return data.GroupBy(x => x.Counterparty)
                       .Select(x => new ReportCustomerKey
                       {
                           Counterparty = x.Key,
                           rc = x.Select(i => new ReportCustomers
                           {
                               TradeDate = i.TradeDate,
                               Isin = i.Ir.Isin
                           }).ToList()
                       });
        }
    }
}
```

I need to iterate over the `IEnumerable<ReportCustomerKey>` and compare the `counterparty` field with the `IEnumerable<Customers>` `customer` field. When these fields are the same, I need the `email` property of `Customers` to be added to the `IEnumerable<ReportCustomerKey>`. I'm having a hard time imagining how I can do this, could someone help? Output example:

```
[
    {
        "counterparty": "Santander",
        "email": "santander@hotmail.com",
        "rc": [
            {
                "tradeDate": "2020-05-23T10:03:12",
                "isin": "DOL110",
                "typology": 0
            },
            {
                "tradeDate": "2020-06-11T11:24:08",
                "isin": "LIT300",
                "typology": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "counterparty": "Jordan Banks",
        "email": "jordan@hotmail.com"
        "rc": [
            {
                "tradeDate": "2020-06-11T11:23:22",
                "isin": "LIT250",
                "typology": 0
            },
            {
                "tradeDate": "2020-06-11T18:08:44",
                "isin": "CIT450",
                "typology": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "counterparty": "Itau",
        "email": "itau@hotmail.com"
        "rc": [
            {
                "tradeDate": "2020-06-11T18:06:53",
                "isin": "LIT350",
                "typology": 0
            },
            {
                "tradeDate": "2020-06-11T18:07:10",
                "isin": "LIT450",
                "typology": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you could use [**Join**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netcore-3.1) to get common data based on matching keys (`Counterparty`,`Customer`), like the following code :

1 -  Add `Email` property to `ReportCustomerKey`:

```
public class ReportCustomerKey
{
    public string Counterparty { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ReportCustomers> rc { get; set; }
.....
}
```

2 - Use `Join` like :

```
IEnumerable<Customers> customers;
IEnumerable<ReportCustomerKey>;

List<ReportCustomerKey> result = reportCustomers.Join(customers,
    rc => rc.Counterparty,
    c => c.Customer,
    (rc, c) =>
    new ReportCustomerKey
    {
        Counterparty = rc.Counterparty,
        Email = c.Email,
        rc = rc.rc
    }).ToList();
```

3 - Demo :

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thanks, very useful!